# crontab error: Too many levels of symbolic links (root)

Tags: arch-linux, cron

In Arch Linux, when I run `sudo crontab -e`, I get this error.

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: Too many levels of symbolic links
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 126
```

I have the package `cronie` installed.

Comment: What happens if you start the `vi` editor using `/usr/bin/vi`? If `vi` is not your ordinary editor, try setting the `VISUAL` and/or `EDITOR` environment variables to some other editor (e.g. `emacs`).

Comment: @Kusalananda If I run `/usr/bin/vi`, the terminal says `-bash: /usr/bin/vi: Too many levels of symbolic links`.

Comment: Updated my question to specify trying to do this as root

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe I have vim set as my default text editor. When I run `sudo EDITOR=nano crontab -e` I can edit root's crontab just fine.